# Customizing 2 buttons separately in AlertDialog (Android Studio, java)

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I'm new to Android development, and I'm making my first java app - a simple tic-tac-toe game in Android Studio.

When someone wins or there is a draw, the app displays a `AlertDialog` message, with title, description, and two buttons: `OK`, and `PLAY AGAIN`.

I wanted it to look a bit different - The `OK` button on the left, with different color, for example red, and the second - purple - button, on the right.

I was inspired by this message while before deleting the board in Trello app. It looks like this:

[image: Example from Trello app]

---

And in my app it looks like this:

[image: My app]

---

I use this function:

```java
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle(playerTwoName + " Won!")
        .setMessage("Congratulations! You won in " + timer_minutes + " minutes and " + timer_seconds + " seconds!")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // ...
                }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("PLAY AGAIN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // ...
                }
        })
        .setCancelable(false);

builder.create();
```

Comment: Try the Neutral button.

Comment: @blackapps sorry, I did something wrong. Now it works - `OK` button is on the left, but is there any way I can change its color?

Comment: I think you will have to write your own customdialog if you want more control.